# Why do we use lowercase $k$ for fields?

Tags: notation

As a general rule in mathematical notation, structures and collections are given uppercase names, while elements often have lowercase names. However, it's not uncommon for a field to be called $k$ (for example in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356878/)). I know that this stands for the German word for field, *Körper*, but why lowercase?

Comment: Little $k$ for the small field, big $K$ for the big field (say, the function field of a variety over $k$)...

Comment: just a guess, but one extra ingredient in German was the prevalence of Fraktur for quite a while, still used for Lie algebras. Also, I always use upp er case for fields., so i think you are talking about specialists in some mathematics areas but not others.

Comment: @WillJagy: yes, I deliberately said "not uncommon" rather than "usual". *F* and *K* seem to be at least as common as *k*.

Comment: Just checked, Lam is consistent in always using upper case in Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields, AMS_GSM 67 (2004 or 2005). He uses a bar or a tilde or a dot directly over the letter to indicate related fields/things. Right, ~ is tilde, but Tilda Swinton. Also, PSG 3, Chelsea 1.

Comment: The other question makes me think you could check by (modern) influential or prolific authors. Did Serge Lang usually use lower case for fields?

Comment: @WillJagy, the second sentence of Chapter 1 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* says, "We work over a fixed algebraically closed field $k$."  Similarly, Section 2 of Chapter V in Weil's *Basic Number Theory* begins, "From now on, until the end of this Chapter, $k$ will denote an algebraic number-field."  Lang also uses $k$ to denote a field in his book *Algebra*, but I can't locate where he first does so (the first appearance I could easily find is on page 162).

Comment: @BarryCipra, that is pretty convincing. Hartshorne, in the undergraduate Geometry: Euclid and Beyond, uses upper case; note that he deliberately avoids fields as much as possible in favor of an axiomatic/synthetic approach. So, I would say there is a bit of a split, either by level of book or overall subject matter.