# Why is K the letter denoting fields?

Tags: field-theory, terminology, math-history

Apologies if this question doesn't adhere to site rules or whatever.

Basically, the title. Is there a reason?

Comment: Deutsch: [Körper (Algebra)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper_(Algebra)).

Comment: In Dutch it is often the $L$ of "lichaam" (Dutch for körper).

Comment: Same as $\Bbb Z$ for the integers.

Answer (score 2):

It abbreviates the German word "Körper". Here is the very first link I found when searching for "letter k for field": [Why do we use lowercase $k$ for fields?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737163/why-do-we-use-lowercase-k-for-fields)